# Binding to property of datacontext parent- WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="?" Binding="{Binding l}">
          </DataGridTextColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

In DataContext of the DataGrid there is the collection of class X:

```
public ObservableCollection<xxx> col{ get; set; }// = DataContext of DG

    private string lName;

    public string LName
    {
        get { return lName; }
        set
        {
            lName= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LName");
        }
    }
```

I want lName will be the header of a particular column in DataGrid

I try this way:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding l}">//l=prop of xxx class that contains the collection
                                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.LName,
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

**It did not work**

how can do this?

Comment: What is `l` - Please post a better example of your ViewModel

Comment: I edited the question, if it is so necessary then l is a string and also working with Notify ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.LName}`

Also I wouldn't play with name cases. WPF is pretty case-sensivity. Avoid of using one-symbol names

Comment: This does not appear to work because the DataGridColumn is not apart of the visual tree. So it can't do the lookup. Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window' This is on the VisibilityProperty in the column.

This question seems to answer it with x:Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Binding paths are also case-sensitive. There is no property `lName` in your DC.