# Bind to Control's Property inside VisualStateManager

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I searched for this Problem on Stackoverflow, but in my opinion the other Posts do not cover this question.

In my Custom Control i am using a Visual State Manager. Inside the Visual State Manager there is an Animation that Animates the Height of an Element. When i try to bind to the Controls Properties i get following Error on StartUp:

> Additional information: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MyNameSpace.MyControl, AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ActualHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=562002); target property is 'To' (type 'Nullable`1')

My Control looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" >
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="someElement"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                                        From="0"
                                                        To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyControl},  Path=CustomControlProperty}"
                                                        Duration="0:0:.7" />
...
```

I tried all ways of Bindings, but it seems that the Animations always takes itself as Scope.

Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Yes, there won't be a visual tree relationship to the parent control from in there, so that's going to fail. But `RootGrid` will have the same `ActualHeight` as the templated parent, won't it? I'd try `{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=RootGrid}`. It's kind of a kludge, yeah. If it even works.

Comment: I made a mistake. I dont want to bind to the Height Property. If this was the case you are right. I want to bind to a custom Property defined inside my Custom Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this [with a `BindingProxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/424129). I find binding proxies to be nonintuitive. Sometimes they work on the first shot; this one took a little trial and error. Also, they're a little bit of a hail-mary workaround.

XAML:

```
<Grid 
    x:Name="RootGrid"
    >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- 
        When defined in ControlTemplate.Resources, this failed. 
        TemplateBinding failed too. 
        -->
        <local:BindingProxy
            x:Key="CustomControlPropertyProxy"
            Data="{Binding CustomControlProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="someElement"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                        From="0"
                        To="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource CustomControlPropertyProxy}}"
                        Duration="0:0:5"
                        />
                </Storyboard>
```

C# (stolen, not for the first time, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/424129)):

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object),
                                     typeof(BindingProxy));
}
```

Here's another variant of the XAML, in case you end up binding animation properties to more than one property of the templated parent:

```
<Grid 
    x:Name="RootGrid"
    >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy
            x:Key="TemplatedParentProxy"
            Data="{Binding ., RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="someElement"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                        From="0"
                        To="{Binding Data.CustomControlProperty, Source={StaticResource TemplatedParentProxy}}"
                        Duration="0:0:5"
                        />
                </Storyboard>
```

### Blind Alleys

After ruling out `TemplateBinding` and `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`, my next guess was to bind `RootGrid.Tag` to `CustomControlProperty` and use `To="{Binding Tag, ElementName=RootGrid}"`. That did not work. While intellisense knew about `RootGrid` in the XAML designer, the `Binding` couldn't find `RootGrid` at runtime:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="someElement"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
    From="0"
    To="{Binding Tag, ElementName=RootGrid, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
    Duration="0:0:1"
    />
```

Debug trace:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=15221148): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=15221148): Framework mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=15221148): Resolving source  (last chance)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=15221148): Framework mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Tag; DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=44950942); target property is 'To' (type 'Nullable`1')
```

That "governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement" jazz is the essential problem with all of the other approaches as well. That's where binding proxies come in: Resource lookup isn't limited by that visual tree parent chain stuff.

Comment: I tried this and it Looks good on the first try. I will mark this answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I realized my answer doesn't work after all.

See this related discussion https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/027c364f-5d75-424f-aafd-7fb76b10b676/templatebinding-on-storyboard?forum=wpf

> [...] The `To` property and `From` property of `ColorAnimation` can't be
>   bind with, because of  those properties need to be frozen
>   (unchangeable) for the animation to work.
>
> So please use specific color to instead of binding.

This suggests that some animation elements are not supposed to change via dynamic properties. I actually don't know whether this applies to all animations or just to a specific subset.

So considering @EdPlunkett answer, it might be worth to investigate, whether subsequent property changes are actually reflected in the animation without errors.

---

You should use `{TemplateBinding CustomControlProperty}` for one way binding or `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=CustomControlProperty}` if you need more binding complexity, instead of trying to find the templated control by other means.

Comment: *"This suggests that some animation elements are not supposed to change via dynamic properties"* -- I wouldn't suppose that myself; if the designers went to the trouble of making it a writable dependency property, they had no objection to it being a binding target. And having tested the code in my answer and found it to work without weirdness or errors, I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: I tried your first solution, too. But hadn't enough time to post my result here, sorry. Thanks anyways. I will try @Ed Plunkett answer now.