# How to change visualstate values and reuse the control with different properties values?

Tags: wpf, triggers, custom-controls, reusability, visualstatemanager

I've realized a custom textbox that changes BorderBrush on `MouseOver` event (in this case it changes the BorderBrush, but I can change other properties).

Now if I want to customize the color of BorderBrush on `MouseOver` and create different textboxes with different "BorderBrush on MouseOver" colors, how to do it using visualstates?
Is there a way without define a different style for every textbox?

```
<ResourceDictionary>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:IconTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconTextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Green" />
                                                <!-- I want to change that Green -->

                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                    Focusable="False"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a separate style for changing the color. You can add a dependency property to your IconTextBox and change the color based on the property.

Declare a dependency property in IconTextBox.cs:

```
public Color MouseOverBorderBrushColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(MouseOverBorderBrushColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MouseOverBorderBrushColorProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBorderBrushColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MouseOverBorderBrushColor", typeof(Color), 
    typeof(IconTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Bind to the property in your style:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:IconTextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="Border"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Border.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Storyboard x:Key="ColorStoryboard">
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                        Value="{Binding MouseOverBorderBrushColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Border.Resources>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" Storyboard="{StaticResource ColorStoryboard}" />

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
            Focusable="False"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Note that you can't use TemplatedParent in VisualStateManager hence I added the storyboard as a static resource to the resources of the border and used that in VisualStateManager. This trick is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126424/is-there-a-way-to-change-specific-properties-of-a-controltemplate-defined-in-a-b).

Then you can have IconTextBoxes with different mouse over border brush colors:

```
<local:IconTextBox MouseOverBorderBrushColor="Green" />
<local:IconTextBox MouseOverBorderBrushColor="Red" />
```