# WPF DataGrid dynamic columns based on object type and subtype

Tags: wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, listcollectionview

I'm building a WPF software to manage a stock of electronics components.

I have the following structure:

```
public class Part
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Resistor : Part
{
    public string Resistance { get; set;}
    public string Power { get; set;}
} 
public class Capacitor : Part
{
    public string Capacitance { get; set; }
    public string Voltage { get; set; }
}
```

Resistor and Capacitor are subtypes of Part.

I'm binding a `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection<Part>`, and using a `ListCollectionView` to add filtering and grouping functionality.

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I filter the `ListCollectionView` to get only the `Resistor` subtype, I want the `DataGrid` to update it's columns to show the properties of `Resistor` type and it's base class `Part` (so I would get the columns Manufacturer, PartNumber, Resistance and Power). At the same time, if I filter the `ListCollectionView` to get `Capacitor` subtype, the `DataGrid` should have the `Capacitor` class public properties and the `Part` public properties (Manufacturer, PartNumber, Capacitance and Voltage).
Finally, If there's no filtering applied, the `DataGrid` would show only `Part` properties (Manufacturer and PartNumber).

I tried to use the `AutoGenerateColumns=true` but the `DataGrid` only shows `Part` properties, even if I filter the `ListCollectionView` to have only `Resistors`. I also tried to change the type of the `ObservableCollection` to `dynamic` and it didn't work either.

How can I change the `DataGrid` columns based on type of the object contained in the `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using autogenerate.  Simply implement the ITypedList interface on the observable collection...

```
public class Parts : ObservableCollection<Part>, ITypedList
{
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        if(Count == 0)
        {
            return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Part));
        }
        else
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this[0]);
            return pdc;
        }
    }

    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return "Parts";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but the GetItemProperties is called only when application is lauched. I need it to be refreshed everytime filtering is applied the the ListViewCollection obtained from the ObservableCollection. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but not very elegant...

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = PartCollection;

Comment: Thanks. Worked nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do this.  Do not auto generate columns.  Set up every column that is possible.  Then bind the visibility of each column to a converter that determines whether the column is visible.

```
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding PartCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer" Binding="{Binding Manufacturer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Number" Binding="{Binding PartNumber}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Power" Binding="{Binding Power}" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.PartCollection, Source={x:Reference dummyElement}, Converter={StaticResource ColumnVisibility}, ConverterParameter=Resistor}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resistance" Binding="{Binding Resistance}" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.PartCollection, Source={x:Reference dummyElement}, Converter={StaticResource ColumnVisibility}, ConverterParameter=Resistor}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Capacitance" Binding="{Binding Capacitance}" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.PartCollection, Source={x:Reference dummyElement}, Converter={StaticResource ColumnVisibility}, ConverterParameter=Capacitor}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Voltage" Binding="{Binding Voltage}" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.PartCollection, Source={x:Reference dummyElement}, Converter={StaticResource ColumnVisibility}, ConverterParameter=Capacitor}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

here is the static resource for the converter...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColumnVisibilityConverter x:Key="ColumnVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

here is the converter...

```
    public class ColumnVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Part> collection = value as ObservableCollection<Part>;
        string collectionType = parameter as string;
        if(collection != null && collectionType != null && collection.Count > 0)
        {
            switch(collectionType)
            {
                case "Resistor": return collection[0].GetType() == typeof(Resistor) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
                case "Capacitor": return collection[0].GetType() == typeof(Capacitor) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
                default: return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

I struggled a bit with binding visibility to the data grid column.  Found the answer here: [Binding Visibility for DataGridColumn in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf)

Setting up the columns manually is best practice in my view.  If you really want to autogenerate them, there is another way to do this.  You can implement an ICustomTypeDescriptor on your collection to return the PropertyDescriptors for the properties of the derived type that is contained in the collection.

Comment: I used your idea to create a boolean property and bind the column visibility to that property. Worked!

Comment: @aquirky I will test but would this create a binding error when it tries to display a column that binds to a property that doesn't exist for the type?

Comment: Well no it doesn't create a binding error. Little confused over that. This works great Thanks!!!!