# WPF DataGrid: Binding to Parent object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Here is my code behind

```
public partial class ChallanListView : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChallanDS> challans = ChallanModel.GetChallansList();
    public ObservableCollection<QualityDS> qualities = ChallanModel.GetQualitiesList();

    public ChallanListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChallansDataGrid.DataContext = this;
        ChallansDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.challans;
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="ChallansDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Challan Date" Binding="{Binding ChallanDate, StringFormat=d}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quality" Binding="?????????????????">
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For Quality cell I want to bind it to "qualities" list which is in my ChallanListView. How can I do that.

Comment: @mm8 can't we make use of Ancestor feature? I am new to WPF and MVVM.

Comment: Definitely not. A DataGridColumn has no visual ancestor to begin with.

Comment: And a column must have a "connection" to a property of the underlying data object for the DataGrid to function as expected. So just forget about this. Add a property to your ChallanDS class and set it on all objects that you intend to display and edit in the DataGrid.

Comment: thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can only bind a column to a property of the data object in the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`. That's how a `DataGrid` works.

So you should move whatever property you want to bind to to the `ChallanDS` class.

Comment: It's not impossible. Just have to work around the visual tree issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf