# The column is not completly collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to collapse a column according to a condition with this code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding="{Binding MyProperty}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0cm"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisView, Path=DataContext.MyboolProperty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2.5cm"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The problem is that the column is not complete collapsed, I can see a part of the column.

I have tried this code too:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding="{Binding MyProperty}"
        Width="0cm"
        Visibility="Collapsed">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisView, Path=DataContext.MyboolProperty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2.5cm"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

In this case the column is collapsed as expected, but then if the property if the trigger is true, the column is still collapsed.

Also I have tried this option:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn" Binding="{Binding MyProperty}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisView, Path=DataContext.MyboolProperty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2.5cm"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisView, Path=DataContext.MyboolProperty}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0cm"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But the behavior is the same than first option, it is not full collapsed but it works when the property of the trigger is true.

Comment: The data trigger is changing visibility of column header, not column (as in second example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data trigger is located inside column **header** template, therefore it can only change properties of column header (not a complete column, i.e. cells).

There is no `Style` for `DataGridTextColumn`, so you can't use `DataTrigger`. But converter should do.

However, another problem is that columns aren't in visual tree, so you can't use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`, they simply won't work. There is an easy [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/1997232) however. Then your column will look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter" />
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn"
                    Binding="{Binding MyProperty}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Data.MyboolProperty, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution, and also to explain more general basic concepts.