# IValueConverter error for DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

So I have a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` `ColCID` whose value depends on another cell of the row `ColSID` (see below code). I tried to implement it with an IValueConverter but I get this error:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=18018639); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ColSID" Header="Guild"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="SID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ColCID" Header="Channel"
                        ItemsSource="{ Binding ElementName=ColSID, Converter={StaticResource ChannelConverter} }"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="CID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Converter:

```
public class ChannelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Guild guild = SenderView.Guilds.Find(g => g.SID == value.ToString());
        if (guild != null) return guild.Channels;
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
...
public class Guild
{
    public class Channel
    {
        public string CID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public string SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you have `SenderView.Guilds.Find(g => g.SID == value.ToString());` in your converter. Were you really trying to find all the items whose SID was equal to `"System.Windows.Controls.DataGridComboBoxColumn"`? Because you're trying to pass a DataGridComboBoxColumn to that converter as the value, and that's what its ToString() method will return, but I don't think that's your intent. What *is* your intent? What are you trying to pass into the converter, and get back out of it? `Guild` has no `CID` property; what are you trying to bind `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to?

Comment: Are you doing this all just to look up the Channels property for the row you're already on?

Comment: What are you trying to bind to ItemSource of your second ComboBox?

Comment: @EdPlunkett basically I want to give each row it's own `ComboBox` for `Channel`, which depends on the selected `Guild`

Comment: @FadedCoder So you want to select from the Channels property of the selected Guild for the row?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes

Comment: @FadedCoder Easy. I'll have an update in a minute

Comment: @FadedCoder See update.

Comment: @EdPlunkett checking, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like for each row in your grid, you want the user to be able to select a `Guild`, and a `Channel` for the `Guild`. Each `Guild` has its own collection of `Channel`, so we're going to select from that collection. I'm going to bind the Channel and Guild objects, not just their IDs. We could do it the other way if you prefer, but I find it easier to let the ComboBox look up the object, instead of the rest of my code having to do it. The SID or CID is right there on the selected object when I want it.

Here's how you can do that. You can't conventionally bind anything to `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource` in your XAML. Any solution involving that property is going to be a little it exotic at best, but it's entirely unnecessary: You can bind the ComboBox's ItemsSource via ElementStyle and EditingElementStyle. `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValueBinding` do work, but I didn't use them.

I wrote a quick stand-in for the parent viewmodel, which owns the collections of Guilds that the user can select from. Note that I also moved your `Channel` class out of `Guild`. The only reason I did that was so I could have a `Channel` property on the `Guild` class for the selected channel. If you'd rather keep `Channel` where you had it, simply rename `Guild`'s `Channel` property to `SelectedChannel` or something like that, and alter the bindings in the XAML accordingly.

The "framework mentor" nonsense is because the columns aren't child controls in the visual tree. They're an instruction to the DataGrid to create a column header, and also a cell in each row. Those headers and cells, and so also their templated content, are in the visual tree. `SelectedItemBinding` isn't a binding on the column; it's a binding that the column creation code will *set on* the SelectedItem property of a ComboBox that it will eventually create in the cell content. But the `ItemsSource` property is just a property of the column itself. You could bind it [with a binding proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/424129), and people do, but binding proxies are the coward's way out.

XAML

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Selections}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Grid.Row="1"
    >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="GuildComboStyle">
            <Setter 
                Property="ItemsSource" 
                Value="{Binding DataContext.Guilds, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" 
                />
        </Style>
        <Style 
            TargetType="ComboBox" 
            x:Key="ChannelComboStyle"
            >
            <!-- Our DataContext here is a GuildSelection object, so we look at its Guild
            property for a collection of Channels to use.
            -->
            <Setter  Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Guild.Channels}" />
            <!-- If there's no selected Guild, prompt the user to select one. -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Guild}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Please select a Guild" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
            Header="Guild"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Guild, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
            ElementStyle="{StaticResource GuildComboStyle}"
            EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource GuildComboStyle}"
            Width="200"
            />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
            Header="Channel"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Guild.Channel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
            ElementStyle="{StaticResource ChannelComboStyle}"
            EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource ChannelComboStyle}"
            Width="200"
            />

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Guild.SID}" Header="Guild SID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Guild.Name}" Header="Guild Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Guild.Channel.CID}" Header="Channel CID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Guild.Channel.Name}" Header="Channel Name" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<GuildSelection> Selections { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Guild> Guilds { get; set; }
}

public class GuildSelection : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Guild Property
    private Guild _guild = null;
    public Guild Guild
    {
        get { return _guild; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _guild)
            {
                _guild = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Guild Property
}

public class Channel
{
    public string CID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Guild : ViewModelBase
{
    public string SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Channel> Channels { get; set; }

    #region Channel Property
    private Channel _channel = null;
    public Channel Channel
    {
        get { return _channel; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _channel)
            {
                _channel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Channel Property
}

#region ViewModelBase Class
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propName = null) 
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
#endregion ViewModelBase Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an `ElementStyle` and bind to the `SID` property that gets set when you select an item in `ColSID`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ColSID" Header="Guild"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="SID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ColCID" Header="Channel"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedValuePath="CID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SID, Converter={StaticResource ChannelConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SID, Converter={StaticResource ChannelConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: This did it. By the way, the data loads after some time, so it doesn't show the channels as soon as it has loaded (Guilds is shown since `ItemsSource` is set in C# code) . Is there any way to make it refresh the `ItemsSource` ?

Comment: @FadedCoder: The `ComboBox` isn't shown until you double click on the cell to edit it anyway, is it?

Comment: Nope. But it shows blank until I enter a new row and double click on the cell again.