# I can't get the property of the view model in the multi value converter

Tags: wpf, datagrid, imultivalueconverter

I have a `DataGrid`. I want to decide when to collapse a column and when to show it.

This is my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
<UserControl.Resources>
```

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiValueConverter}">
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource ProxyElement}" Path="DataContext.MyPropertyInViewModel" />
      <Binding Source="1"/>
   </MultiBinding>
</DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
```

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   //Do  the conversion
}
```

I need the proxy element to access the view model from an element that doesn't belong to the visual tree.

In the `MultiBinding`, the second binding works. In the converter I receive the value `1`, but the problem is with the first element. I don't get the property of the view model, that it is a `string`. I get a `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

How can I pass a property of my view model to the multi-value converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProxyElement` will not bind the data context in `Resources` as it is not part of the visual tree. To make this work, define the `FrameworkElement` anywhere in the visual tree, e.g. like below in a `Grid`. The `DataContext` is inherited, but you can also set it explicitly. Set the `Visibility` of the proxy to `Collapsed`, so it is hidden.

```
<Grid>
   <!-- ...grid definitions. -->
   <FrameworkElement Grid.Row="42" x:Name="ProxyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

Reference it using `x:Reference`, since `ElementName` bindings only work in the visual tree, but columns are not part of it.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiValueConverter}">
      <Binding Source="{x:Reference ProxyElement}" Path="DataContext.InitialDepositAmount"/>
      <Binding Source="1"/>
   </MultiBinding>
</DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
```

A better way is to use a `Freezable` as binding proxy. Those can access the data context even outside of the visual tree. See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf) that shows an approach with a custom `BindingProxy`, that also works in `Resources` and without `x:Reference`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution for I asked and the advise for a better solution.