# c# WPF Binding to a property of DataConext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem with Bindings in WPF(c#).

This is my xaml:

```xml
<my:ComboColumn Header="{Binding PropHeader}"
                 DataMemberBinding="{Binding Prop}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleProps}"
                 Width="*"
                 />
```

If I use this binding:

```cs
Binding binding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ItemsSource)),
                Source = this
            };
```

Then the binding path is correct (is looking for PossibleProps),
but is looking at the false Source.
Is binding to property `PossibleProps` in the `ViewModel`.

If I use this binding:

```cs
Binding binding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ItemsSource)),
                Source = DataContext
            };
```

Then the binding path is false(is looking for ItemsSource),
but is looking at the source I want.
Is binding to property `ItemsSource` in the `MainViewModel`.

Can you help me please?

#### update1:

full code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView;

namespace DB_Admin_WPF.Controls
{
    public partial class ComboColumn : GridViewDataColumn
    {

        public static DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid?, string>>), typeof(ComboColumn), new PropertyMetadata());
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid?, string>> ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid?, string>>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public override FrameworkElement CreateCellElement(GridViewCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            var element = new TextBlock();
            var valueBinding = new Binding(DataMemberBinding.Path.Path)
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                Converter = new ConverterKeyValue() 
            };
            element.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, valueBinding);

            return element;
        }



        public override FrameworkElement CreateCellEditElement(GridViewCell cell, object dataItem)
        {

            Binding binding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ItemsSource)),
                Source = DataContext
            };

            var element = new RadComboBox();
            element.SetBinding(RadComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, DataMemberBinding);
            element.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
            element.SetBinding(RadComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
            return element;
        }

        //public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid?, string>> ItemSource { get; set; }


        public ComboColumn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

#### Update2

So I did share now the complete code. The xaml is how I want to use my class `ComboColumn`

The `DataContext` refers to the `MainViewModel` while this refers to a `ViewModel`, which is in a list in the ´MainViewModel´.

In the binding, I want to refer to `PossibleProps` at the `MainViewModel`.

Comment: its not clear what you're trying to do here.  You have created a binding in your xaml, why are you then creating bindings in your code?

Comment: @TimRutter Sry for my bad explanation. I am not that comfortable writing in English. I hope you get my point after the edit.

Comment: @peni4142: What is correct and what is not? What property are you trying to bind to and from where? Where is `PossibleProps` and how are you supposed to bind the `ItemsSource` property to this one?

Comment: @mm8 I try to bind  `PossibleProps` at the `MainViewModel`

Comment: @peni4142: From where? The XAML markup?

Comment: @peni4142 your english is perfectly fine :)

Comment: @mm8 Yeah the XAML markup is how I would like to make use of the class ComboColumn. The element `my:ComboColumn` is a child of `telerik:RadGridView.Columns`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleProps}"` binding will always fail since a `DataGridColumn` doesn't inherit any `DataContext` to bind to.

`Binding` (or `DataMemberBinding`) is a *Binding*  type property that is applied to the generated element at runtime. It's not resolved from the column.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf) answer for an example of how use a `Freezable` to be able to bind  the `Visibility` property of a column to a source property.

Comment: When I set the `Source` of the binding to `DataContext`, I get that output: 'ItemsSource' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel'
So I think there is a DataContext.

Comment: No. When you set the `Source` explicitly, you don't bind to any inherited `DataContext`.