# Binding to a MainViewModel command from an ItemsControl Button in Avalonia

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I am trying to create a ReactiveUI MVVM binding from an ItemsControl Button in Avalonia
In WPF this would be done via a Freezable BindingProxy. However, it looks like Freezable isn't available in Avalonia. How should such a binding be created?

```
            <ItemsControl Items="{Binding MyQueue}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <Button Content="My Button"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                          Command="{Binding MySpecialCmd}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

References:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf%5C)
https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big thanks to @maxkatz6 on the AvaloniaUI gitter.
Here is the solution:

```
{Binding $parent[ItemsControl].DataContext.MySpecialCmd}
```

```
           <ItemsControl Items="{Binding MyQueue}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <Button Content="My Button"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                          Command="{Binding $parent[ItemsControl].DataContext.MySpecialCmd}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Avalonia version 11.0.0 need **off** **`CompileBinding`** param.

> `x:CompileBindings="False"`

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried the answer of @AndyPrince but got served with an error of the type

> Unable to resolve property or method of name 'MySpecialCmd' on type
> 'System.Object'

This is caused by the compiled bindings being unable to know the real type of the datacontext.
However, there is a workaround by casting :

```
Command="{Binding $parent[ItemsControl].((vm:MyViewModel)DataContext).MySpecialCmd}"
```