# I get System.Windows.Style as text of the ToolTip of the header in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I want to define a style for the datagrid columns that get the text of the tooltip through an attached property. But I get the text `System.Windows.Style` instead of the text.

The code is this. XML resource file that defines the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderConTooltip">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <!--Para poder utilizar el attached propery, se tiene que utilizar PlacementTarget, y además indicar que el source
                                es el control padre, que es el tooltip, porque el TextBlck no pertenece al mismo visual tree.-->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.(ap:CabeceraDatagridAttachedProperty.Tooltip), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"  MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The code in the xaml:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cantidad Para Descontar" Binding="{Binding CantidadParaDescontar, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="AUTO" IsReadOnly="false"
                                ap:CabeceraDatagridAttachedProperty.Tooltip="tooltip cabecera por attached property"
                                HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderConTooltip}">
```

The attached property:

```
namespace GTS.CMMS.Client.AttachedProperties
{
    public static class CabeceraDatagridAttachedProperty
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Tooltip",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CabeceraDatagridAttachedProperty));

        public static string GetTooltip(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(TooltipProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTooltip(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TooltipProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the text System.Windows.Style instead of the text.

This is expected, since you assigned a style to the `ToolTip` property instead of content. The `ToolTip` does not have any idea how to display a `Style`, so it calls `ToString()`.

What you should do is bind the desired attached property directly to the `ToolTip` property. Use `Self` as `RelativeSource` to refer to the underlying `DataGridColumnHeader`. Then navigate to its `Column` property and specify your attached property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderConTooltip">
   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
   <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Column.(local:CabeceraDatagridAttachedProperty.Tooltip), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works if in my view I set a text in hard code. But if I try to bind a property of the object that is source of the row, it doesn't work. I am trying something like ap:CabeceraDatagridAttachedProperty.Tooltip="{Binding Path=Myproperty}"

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía That is a completely different issue. It originates from data grid columns not being part of the visual tree. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22073740/6181599) for solutions.