# WPF datagrid where the header and number of columns is generated dynamically using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am trying to create a generic `DataGrid` in my WPF application where the number of columns and the value of each of their headers is defined through a binding to the class property `ResultsHeader`, which is an array of strings.

Here is what I have so far :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" Margin="10" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Visibility="{Binding ShowResults, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Binding="{Binding [0]}"
                            Header="{Binding ResultsHeader[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowResultsColumns[0], Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Binding="{Binding [1]}"
                            Header="{Binding ResultsHeader[1], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowResultsColumns[1], Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Binding="{Binding [2]}"
                            Header="{Binding ResultsHeader[2], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowResultsColumns[2], Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" Binding="{Binding [3]}"
                            Header="{Binding ResultsHeader[3], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowResultsColumns[3], Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In which `Results` represents the content of the cells of the table, `ShowResults` is the boolean that controls whether or not the `DataGrid` is visible or collapsed, and `ShowResultsColumns` is an array of booleans that controls whether each of the individual columns is visible or collapsed. Here is how each of the variables and properties is coded within the ViewModel class :

```
private static readonly int maxNumberOfColumnsInResults = 4;

private ObservableCollection<string[]> _results;
public ObservableCollection<string[]> Results
{
    get { return _results; }
    set {
        _results = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Results));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowResults));
    }
}

public bool ShowResults
{
    get { return _results != null; }
}

private string[] _resultsHeader;
public string[] ResultsHeader
{
    get { return _resultsHeader; }
    set {
        _resultsHeader = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ResultsHeader));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShowResultsColumns));
    }
}

public bool[] ShowResultsColumns
{
    get
    {
        return _resultsHeader == null
                    ? Enumerable.Repeat(false, maxNumberOfColumnsInResults).ToArray()
                    : Enumerable.Range(0, maxNumberOfColumnsInResults).Select(x => x < ResultsHeader.Length).ToArray();
    }
}
```

`BooleanToVisibilityConverter` and `OnPropertyChanged` seem to be correctly implemented based on their behaviors on other features of the application, and my variables are assigned the correct values. The binding works on `Results` and `ShowResults` fine, but not on `ResultsHeader` and `ShowResultsColumns` (all the columns are visible with an empty header regardless of the value of `_resultsHeader`). Is there something I am missing ? Should I change my approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something I am missing ?

Yes, the fact that a `DataGridColumn` has no `DataContext` that you can bind to.

> Should I change my approach ?

You could use a binding proxy that captures the `DataContext` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/7252182).